Can not develop in Java on airgapped system
I have a Java project which has to be run/debug on a remote Linux machine. This machine is not connected to Internet and I can access it only via SSH.
I am able to tunnel HTTP(S) via SOCKS proxy back to my laptop.
ssh  -R 1080 jumphost
export https_proxy='socks5://localhost:1080'
export http_proxy='socks5://localhost:1080'
mvn verify -DproxySet=true -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080

All this works. I also did set VS Code parameters:
"maven.executable.options": "-DproxySet=true -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080"
"java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-DproxySet=true -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080"

But no matter how I try, the Red Hat Java plugin ignores it. While opening a Java project, it executes:

'Starting Java server with: /home/opc/.vscode-server/extensions/redhat.java-1.35.1/jre/17.0.12-linux-x86_64/bin/java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Djava.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot=false -DDetectVMInstallationsJob.disabled=true -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -Xlog:disable -javaagent:/home/opc/.vscode-server/extensions/redhat.java-1.35.1/lombok/lombok-1.18.33.jar -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/opc/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/94e099226cb372dc049b9fd4eb4826fa-2/redhat.java -Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf -jar /home/opc/.vscode-server/extensions/redhat.java-1.35.1/server/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.900.v20240613-2009.jar -configuration /home/opc/.vscode-server/data/User/globalStorage/redhat.java/1.35.1/config_linux -data /home/opc/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/94e099226cb372dc049b9fd4eb4826fa-2/redhat.java/jdt_ws

My proxy parameters are ignored, which finally fails with:

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:
The following artifacts could not be resolved:
org.hibernate:hibernate-ucp:pom:6.5.0.Final (absent): Could not
transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-ucp:pom:6.5.0.Final from/to
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Network is unreachable

No matter how I try, the Red Hat vscode-java extension ignores my proxy settings.
PS: On the contrary, the Maven extension works just fine.

This question is similar to: How to use SOCKS in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@seenukarthi This seems to be about how to configure things in VS Code so the right options are passed by the extension, not about using SOCKS itself

@MarkRotteveel Yes, I realize that. I retracted my vote.

Does the "remote Linux machine" succeed in connecting to the Internet with a different app with the proxy set?

Don't know if this helps, but FYI: Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code
